# When working with tables, is it possible to have two selectors for one class?

Tags: html, css

Context: I am a newbie to HTML/CSS and am currently building a basic website using Markdown.

I've looked through posts on StackOverflow but was not able to answer my specific question.

I have a basic table:

```
.mytable {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: white;

th {
 padding: 2px;
 height:40px;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #4c4c4c;
 }

td {
   padding: 2px;
   text-align:center; 
   vertical-align:middle;
   border:1px solid #f1eaf2;
}

tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #efefef}
}
```

However, on one table I want to align the text to the right. I attempted some inline styling, i.e., `<td align="right" important!>` but that did not work. So, I'm wondering if it is possible to have two different `<td>`s in the same `<table>` class.

If not, I did find on StackOverflow where I would create two different table classes.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note: The align attribute is obsolete as of HTML5 but doesn't apply to text anyway.

Comment: `.mytable { td }` isn't legal.  You'd want `.mytable td { }`.  Two different table classes is as simple as `.mytableclass1` and `.mytableclass2`

Comment: aligning text in html looks like `<td style="text-align: right">`. Note, `style` implies `!important`

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Also, are you using Sass/Less on this? Otherwise (as Teepeemm pointed out) the CSS is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can align the text in 2 columns differently within the same table. The trick is to apply a `text-align: right` to the 2nd `<td>` element. There are a few ways to do this, in the example below I've used a `td:last-child` selector.

```css
.mytable {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
}
.mytable th {
  padding: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4c4c4c;
}
.mytable td {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f1eaf2;
}
.mytable td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.mytable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #efefef
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1A</td>
    <td>1B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2A</td>
    <td>2B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3A</td>
    <td>3B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```